# TWRequest class. What to do?

Tags: ios, twitter, ios7, social-framework

I update the project, which was written under iOS5. Now do support only iOS7.
The project has check:

if ([TWRequest class]) {
    ...
    }

XCODE says "TWRequest is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0". I know I should use Social.framework.

Therefore, the question whether it makes sense to update these checks, or you can simply remove it? Indeed, in the iOS still supported by default Social.framework?

Comment: If your app will only support iOS 7 then remove ALL references to the outdates APIs and use the new APIs.

Comment: Thank you. I understand.
I have to remove all kinds of test
    if ([TWRequest class]) {
Because they do not make sense?